# Eliminating duplicate values from one column if other column have same value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one single table and I want to avoid the duplicate value based on one column.

[image]

I need to remove the duplicate from CustomerName if it has all the Sites have same Version.

In the table i want line 2, 3, 4, 5(Not 6 as 5 and 6 have same Version) then 7, 9, 10, 11, 12 (Not 13 and 14 as 12,13,14 have version)

Comment: MySQL doesn't return ORA-00933, so I replaced that tag.

Comment: Then done, add a proper UNIQUE constraint to avoid new duplicates to be inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the output as mentioned in my question using distinct in query.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT CUSTOMERNAME, VERSION
FROM
    BOOK1_DATA;
```

Answer (score 1):

This query shows unwanted rows:

```
select * from my_table a where exists (
  select 1 from my_table b 
  where a.CustomerName = b.CustomerName and a.Version = b.Version and a.Sites > b.Sites)
```

If you want to remove them from your table use `delete` instead `select *`.

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/gXoNEtGY)